# Setting project and layer CRS in PyQGIS with setCrs() has no effect on the map canvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm using the following code to set the project CRS in a Python script:

```
#creates the project and projectRoot objects
projectObj = QgsProject.instance()
projectRoot = projectObj.layerTreeRoot()

#sets the project CRS
projectCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(3395)
projectObj.setCrs(projectCrs)
assert projectCrs.isValid()
print(projectCrs.isValid())
```

I'm using the following code in a for-loop to set the CRS for all layers:

```
shpSavedLayer.setCrs(projectCrs)
```

What I get is this:

[image: QGIS Project after setting CRS in Python]

Although, the QGIS Status Bar, Project Properties Window, and Layer Properties Window for every layer state that the CRS is set to EPSG:3395, there is clearly something wrong with the projection.

If I run the same code with the above lines commented out, then set the project CRS to EPSG:3395 via the Project Properties Window, I get this:

[image: QGIS Project after setting CRS manually]

which looks a lot more accurate.

What's happening here? From the discussion on GIS SE, I'm guessing this has to do with the difference between setting the CRS and reprojecting the layer?

Comment: @Kadir I have used the Project Properties Window and Layer Properties Window in the QGIS GUI to set the correct layer and project CRS. When I do this, the image in the Map View "deforms" to display the map correctly. I want to do the same thing using Python. I'm trying to use the ```setCrs()``` method to accomplish this, but they are not "deforming". Does that help clarify the issue? Would it help if I posted the entire script? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I use `projectObj.setCrs(projectCrs)`, map in the canvas deforms. What is your QGIS version?

Comment: @Kadir How do I use PyQGIS to change the CRS of a project or a layer so that it shows on the Map View?

Comment: `projectObj.setCrs(projectCrs)` changes the CRS of a project.

Comment: Do you refresh the map canvas (programattically or using zoom or pan tool) after setting CRS?

Comment: @Kadir Yes, I have refreshed the map canvas after running the script. Sorry for the delay in response. I had a busy weekend and Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
shpSavedLayer.setCrs(projectCrs)
```

*overrides* your layers' CRSs regardless of their coordinates' actual CRS. For that to work properly you must know the actual CRS of your data.

The data you are using https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/Public-Use-Microdata-Areas-PUMA-/cwiz-gcty comes with a PRJ file of

```
GEOGCS[
  "WGS84(DD)", 
  DATUM["WGS84", SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]
]
```

While this is actually a definition for WGS84 (EPSG:4326, at least the parameter values are the same), QGIS fails to properly process this as you must have noticed. But most importantly: That data is not in EPSG:3395.

To fix this, you need to set the layer's CRS separately:

```
layerCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)
shpSavedLayer.setCrs(layerCrs)
```

For the project/canvas you can use whatever CRS you like, EPSG:3395 8WGS 84 / World Mercator) would be a distorted view as well, I would recommend EPSG:26918 (NAD83 / UTM zone 18N) for optimal results.

Comment: So, the SHP file used to make the layers comes from the NYC Housing Development Website. The SHP file has no set CRS. It comes with a ESRI PRJ file that describes the CRS. However, everything I have read suggests that QGIS cannot read PRJ files. That's why I'm trying to set the CRS. Also, I just want to know how to do it with the QGIS Python API.

Comment: 1) Where did you read that? QGIS does read PRJ files. It might fail on some but that would be a different issue. 2) Have you tried my suggestion? 3) If it does not work, can you link to one of the Shapefiles you are using?

Comment: @ bugmenot123 Sorry, I was thinking of [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259946/qgis-how-to-set-crs), which indeed says that QGIS can read PRJ files, but might not be able to convert the reference to the ArcGIS CRS database to the QGIS CRS database. The SHP file, with DBF, PRJ and SHX files, can be downloaded [here](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/Public-Use-Microdata-Areas-PUMA-/cwiz-gcty). I meant to link to it in my last reply.

Comment: Thanks! You didn't add any detail on that in the initial question but seeing the data makes it clear that QGIS does not properly process that PRJ file indeed.

Comment: I updated the answer