# No localization possible for ESRI-layer with CRS 4647 (QGIS 3.22)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I have a point ESRI-layer with CRS 4647, it should show special points along rivers in my region. When I open it in an existing QGIS (3.22) project (CRS EPSG 3044 or EPSG 25832), I do not see any points, though the attribute table exists. When I adapt the CRS of the point layer for example to CRS 3044, the points are visible, but somewhere in the ocean, not in my region (lower saxony, Germany). I tried too to reproject (with QGIS toolbox) the layer, no success. Then I tried to export the layer to a new layer with CRS 3044 - no success. When I open a new project only with the point layer, and add another layer out of my region, the two layers do not fit to another.

Has anybody an idea, what I could do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: Did you try this answer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259946/qgis-how-to-set-crs

Comment: thanks for your ideas. I tried reprojection, also assign projection, nothing worked. But then a colleague found that the problem was the shapefile. It only supposed to bei CRS 4647, in reality it was another. With this tool https://www.aed-sicad.de/fme.html he could repair the shapefile.